# How can I get all the taxonomy term objects from the database regardless of vocabulary?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I can see in the Drupal taxonomy api taxonomy_get_tree() which returns an array of term objects, however, the vocabulary ID is a required object.  I thought also about taxonomy_term_load_multiple, but an array of IDs is necessary to populate it.

How can I get all the objects regardless of vocabulary affiliation? More or less what I am looking for is taxonomy_get_tree('all').

Each term object contains the [vid] it's associated with. I need to be able to loop through each object and determine the vocabulary it's associated with rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`entity_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7) function. The second argument, `$ids`, is defined as such:

> An array of entity IDs, or FALSE to load all entities.

So you can get all taxonomy terms in the database with this simple call:

```
$all_terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', FALSE);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks like being more familiar with entities will save me a lot of work. Where can I get a list of the default entity types? I didn't have much luck with google other than how to create new ones. Thanks again!

Comment: Basically any module that provides an entity has to implement `hook_entity_info()`, so that's the place to look in any specific module. There's a list of all core implementations of that hook [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/implementations/hook_entity_info/7), if you look through those functions and read the `hook_entity_info()` docs it should all make sense :)